# How to join a list of multiprocessing.Process() at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Given a `list()` of running `multiprocessing.Process`-instances, how can I join on all of them and return as soon as one exits without a `Process.join`-timeout and looping?

## Example

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from random import randint
from time import sleep
def run():
    sleep(randint(0,5))
running = [ Process(target=run) for i in range(10) ]

for p in running:
    p.start()
```

How can I block until at least one `Process` in `p` exits?

What I don't want to do is:

```py
exit = False
while not exit:
    for p in running:
        p.join(0)
        if p.exitcode is not None:
            exit = True
            break
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `multiprocessing.Process` then. What you ask is trivial using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`: simply use `map` and call `next` on the iterator.

Comment: `map(Process.join, running)` maybe?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy as far as I can see this will only return once all processes exit. This is not what I want. Added this as clarification to the question. thank you.

Comment: @Bakuriu I don't understand yet how this solves what I want. As far as I can see this will run a process every time I call `next`. I want all processes to start in parallel and detect when at least one exists. If it is so simple can you maybe post a snippet which demonstrates your approach?

Comment: just to be clear- do you really want to exit your application when any of the child processes finish and abandon the rest of them?

Comment: @Paul no.  I just want to stop waiting. The logic triggered after the wait is not important to the question, hence I left it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`multiprocessing.connection.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.wait) (Python 3.3+) to wait on several `Process.sentinel`s at once. A [sentinel](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.sentinel) will become ready, as soon a Process exits and hence unblock the `connection.wait()`.

> **multiprocessing.connection.wait(object_list, timeout=None)**
>
> Wait till an object in object_list is ready. Returns the list of those
>   objects in object_list which are ready. If timeout is a float then the
>   call blocks for at most that many seconds. If timeout is None then it
>   will block for an unlimited period. A negative timeout is equivalent
>   to a zero timeout.
>
> For both Unix and Windows, an object can appear in object_list if it
>   is
>
> - a readable Connection object;
> - a connected and readable socket.socket object; or
> - the sentinel attribute of a Process object.
>
> A connection or socket object is ready when there is data available to
>   be read from it, or the other end has been closed. ...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, connection, current_process
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime


def run():
    sleep(randint(2,10))
    print(f"{datetime.now()} {current_process().name} exiting")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = [Process(target=run) for _ in range(4)]

    for p in pool:
        p.start()

    print(f"{datetime.now()} {current_process().name} waiting")
    connection.wait(p.sentinel for p in pool)
    print(f"{datetime.now()} {current_process().name} unblocked")
```

Example Output:

```
2019-07-22 21:54:07.061989 MainProcess waiting
2019-07-22 21:54:09.062498 Process-3 exiting
2019-07-22 21:54:09.063565 MainProcess unblocked
2019-07-22 21:54:09.064391 Process-4 exiting
2019-07-22 21:54:14.068392 Process-2 exiting
2019-07-22 21:54:17.062045 Process-1 exiting

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I knew that there would be a way just using multiprocessing. Thank you, great answer!

Comment: How could I figure out which of the processes that unblocked main?

Comment: @LennartRolland After starting the processes you convert the `pool`-list to a dictionary, where you map the sentinel-value of a process to the corresponding `Process` instance. Then when `connection.wait()` returns with the sentinel(s) you look up in the `pool`-dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a way to do what you want here exactly as specified- that's just not the way the API is set up. If you can take it up a level to where you create the list of processes though, there are a number of excellent solutions.

Probably the best is to use multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered(). This will take a function and an iterable of inputs, create a bunch of processes, and feed the inputs to the processes. It returns an iterable that the `next` method will wait until a value is ready, and then return each of those as it becomes available.

If you can't work your problem into function + inputs, the next solution is to use some synchronization primitive. For what I am guessing you want to accomplish, I would use a semaphore-

```
sem = Semaphore(0)

def build_proc(the_sem):
    do_some_work
    the_sem.release()

myprocs = [buld_proc(sem) for _ in range(10)]

# in your code-
start_procs(myprocs)
done = 0
while done < len(myprocs):
    sem.acquire()
    do_post_processing()
```

If you really don't need a loop, an Event would work as well, just wait for the first process to set it. If you really can't modify the function that creates the processes in any way, the final solution I could imagine is (pretty bad haha)- use a threadpool to set up a pool of waiters for each process.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED

def waiter(proc):
    proc.join()

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(waiter, p) for p in processes]
    # this will return as soon as one completes
    results = wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

Comment: sorry, but looking at @Darkonaut 's answer I think your answer is not correct. Also using a Semaphore does not do what I want, since that again checks the processes in sequence and does not continue if at least one exists. Unless we fallback to polling and looping.

Comment: Nice, the other answer is definitely better. Spent a while double checking the docs looking for that too haha! However, the Semaphore process is not doing a "check in loop"... its passing the SAME semaphore to all of the child processes. Each child process adds one to the semaphore, and the parent continues whenever it is at 1 or more. The above answer is definitely better though