# Python Multiprocessing - Wait until one process finish its job

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm writing a program to do the same task with multiple processes. So when one process finish its job, how can I stop all others to print the result?

```
procs = []
for _ in range(8):
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=calculateThing)
        procs.append(process)
        process.start()
```

Yes I know that I can use

```
for process in procs:
    process.join()
```

But if for example process 4 will finish its job, I can't know that until processes 1,2,3 finish their jobs.

Comment: why not setting a flag (i.e. `FINISHED=False`) before starting the loop, and in the worker `calculateThing` just look for it: when a worker is done it sets `FINISHED=True`, all other workers will read the flag at each step and abort when necessary

Comment: @nxet is it okay to share the flag as an argument when creating processes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join a list of multiprocessing.Process() at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152073/how-to-join-a-list-of-multiprocessing-process-at-the-same-time)